# &: syntax for methods with arguments

Tags: ruby

I have a nested array:

```
a = [[1, "Aldous Huxley"],
     [3, "Sinclair Lewis"],
     [2, "Ernest Hemingway"],
     [4,"Anthony Burgess"]]
```

`a.collect { |author| author.drop(1) }`

outputs

```
[["Aldous Huxley"], ["Sinclair Lewis"], ["Ernest Hemingway"], ["Anthony Burgess"]]
```

while

`a.collect(&:drop(1))`

Gives me a sintax error.

```
SyntaxError: (irb):18: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
a.collect(&:drop(1))
                  ^
```

Is it possible to define my original block expression in a &: syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colon is part of a [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Symbol.html) in Ruby, the `&` is the magic that makes that syntax work, by calling `to_proc` on the object and using that as a block. So, while you can't use a symbol like `:drop(1)`, you can accomplish this without using a symbol in 2 ways:

1) Return a proc from a method and pass that in:

```
def drop(count)
  proc { |instance| instance.drop(count) }
end
a.collect(&drop(1))
```

2) Pass in an object that responds to `to_proc`:

```
class Drop
  def initialize(how_many = 1)
    @to_drop = how_many
  end

  def to_proc
    proc { |instance| instance.drop(@to_drop) } 
  end
end
drop = Drop.new(1)
a.collect(&drop) # or, more succinctly
a.collect(&Drop.new(1))
```

In a simple case like this, defining methods that return procs or objects that respond to `to_proc` is probably overkill and just passing a block to `collect` is better, but there could be some use cases where it's not.

---

Update: Thinking about this more, the `Symbol` class doesn't have a `call` method, but that doesn't mean it can't:

```
module SymbolCall
  def call(*args)
    proc { |instance| instance.public_send(self, *args) }
  end
end

class Symbol
  include SymbolCall
end

a.collect(&:drop.(1)) # or
a.collect(&:drop.call(1))
```

Just make sure you don't forget that it's actually a method call `:drop.(1)` **not** `:drop(1)`.

Answer (score 6):

No, this is impossible.

`&` syntax is the syntactic sugar, that does literally the following:

- converts the argument to `Proc` instance, calling `to_proc` on it;
- uses the proc as a block, passing arguments from the enumerator to it.

`(&:foo)` works because [`Symbol.to_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) exists.

`(&:foo(arg))` just can not be parsed, since `:` expects valid symbol chars afterwards, and opening parenthesis will raise a syntax error.